# Uncaught ReferenceError: myVarible is not defined in if statement comparing to undefined

Tags: javascript, undefined

Does anyone know why would this happen for below code

```
if(myVarible !=undefined){ myVarible.doSomething() }
```

myVariable is A global object that is used only on some pages 
I am sure I've done this in a past and it always worked.
I also tried

```
if(!!s){}
```

Which I am also sure I've used in the past.

finally got it to work with `if(typeof s!=="undefined"){}`

but I would like to know why undefined variable is not equal to `undefined` 
and why did it work in the past?

Thanks

Comment: Suggestion: what's wrong with `if (!s) {...}`?  Also: look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27509/detecting-an-undefined-object-property

Comment: Because `undefined` can be reassigned, you should always check against the type anyway.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From what I understood, the problem is, that on some pages you don't create the global `myVarible` variable at all.
For such case checks

```
myVarible !== undefined
```

and

```
typeof myVarible !== "undefined"
```

are not equal. The difference is, that only `typeof` operator can handle non-existing references to names (e.g. variables). All other language constructs throw `ReferenceError` when encountering reference that cannot be resolved. `typeof` returns the string `"undefined"` for this case.

So, in your case, you should use the `typeof` operator or check existence of the `variable` property on global object.

```
if (window.myVarible) {}
```

[link to ecma-script specification defining typeof behavior](https://es5.github.io/#x11.4.3)

Answer (score 1):

Use `if(window.myVarible)` instead. If you check for the variable per se, JavaScript will try to execute or check the value of the variable<sup>1</sup> which in turn yields this error message.

You can also use `if(typeof myVarible !== "undefined")` which will only look at the type of the variable but not at its value.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup>The way that JavaScript checks for the value of a variable depends on whether that variable was written as an object property like `window.myVar` or without.</sub>